# Android Pre Compiler error?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am facing a very annoying problem.
I wanted to use [sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) in my project, after long and frustrating search i come to know that i have to update my eclipse + ADT to new one to import that library properly, and i got demo app running fine.

now i want to integrate it in my project, so i import my project in same workspace and i received following error after just importing it.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'MyProject'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I been through many sites plus some questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617830/eclipse-upgrade-not-working) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804558/android-build-errors)  but found nothing concrete. Also i tried different cases that are possible, but they are of no use.

so i am in middle of strange situation, that
library cannot be import on old eclipse(Galileo + ADT v15) , and project can not be import on new eclipse(ADT Bundle eclipse + ADT v21).

somebody please help me on this.

Comment: I guess you have tried the simple things like restarting Eclipse?

Comment: i tried everything that i can imagine, like playing with dependencies, creating new project and coping folder by folder data from myProject (src, bin, res etc), but it is of no use

Comment: have you tried the solution in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617830/eclipse-upgrade-not-working

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you experience bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42051

Do you have any files with no extension in their name, e.g. `README`?
Try adding an extension to the files, e.g. `README` -> `README.txt`.

Do you use Subversion?
Try installing packages:

- Subversive SVN JDT Ignore Extensions
- Subversive SVN Team Provider

Comment: Working !  Thanks Buddy for giving idea that this is all related to "SVN"

Answer (score 12):

I think we suffered from the bug Giorgos Kylafas mentioned.
Luckily Google released an update for the ADT on their Preview Channel as none of the other mentioned solutions helped me.

To Install the updates follow the instructions given in Comment #20 from tnorbye:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42051#c20

This solved the Problem for me.
Here s the DirectLink to the Preview Channel: http://tools.android.com/preview-channel

Comment: This worked for me, but seems an awful hassle. Bad form Google.

Comment: @schmidiii, Thanks for giving exact links for problem.  +1 for your tremendious help !   Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The problem also occurs when you have a referred a library project and you "Close" that project .

So you may try reopening any closed project in the workspace to which you might have referred .

Comment: Thank you! I was trying hours to find out what was going own. Thanks1!!

Answer (score 2):

By the way,

for those who don't want to install package and other things.. there is quick fix ....

1. Search for `svn` in your project folder and delete all folders named as `SVN`(might be hidden).
2. Search for `*.svn` and again delete all file of `.svn` extension
3. Import your Project again.

**IMPORTANT:** I said this is quick solution if you are in hurry, This is not accurate & best solution. It will clear all records of your "svn" for your project.

If you don't know how to re-configure it again then install package mentioned above in **Giorgos Kylafas** and **schmidiii** 's answers , It is perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

It has just happened to me. My project depends on `android-support-v7-appcompat` which was closed. Every time when I pressed `Ctrl + S`, an error dialog showed up. After I had opened `android-support-v7-appcompat`, I didn't see the dialog anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I tried deleting the project from Eclipse and then re-imported the project that was failing.
It all worked fine after that.