# Annoying "Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project" dialog

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse / Android : “Errors running builder ‘Android Pre Compiler’ on project…”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455018/eclipse-android-errors-running-builder-android-pre-compiler-on-project)

I keep getting the following error pop-up every now and then on my Android project on Eclipse 4.2.1:

```
Title:
'Building workspace has encountered a problem. Errors occurred during the build.

Message:
Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'xxxx'. java.lang.NullPointerException
```

FYI, my project has .svn repositories and uses 4 external libraries (that seem to be fine, no errors). I'm using Android 4.2.

What could be the issue here? :(

Comment: Have you tried (a) restarting Eclipse, or (b) Project > Clean?

Comment: Yes, several times. I've also tried to recreate the project from start.

Comment: Glad you found your solution, omegatai! I ran into the same problem, but in my case it turns out restarting eclipse was enough.
(Also, congrats on your recent 1k rep)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone found the answer! In my case, it was the svn extension-less files that were causing the problems. See solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455018/eclipse-android-errors-running-builder-android-pre-compiler-on-project?rq=1).