# ADT does not recreate R.java

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I got quite a large project to work with. After I imported it and fixed project properties I found out that Eclipse just won't create the R.java. Things I've tried:

- Clean, rebuild, un-check "auto build", rebuild again
- Deleting the gen folder (Eclipse recreates it but without R.java)
- Deleting the gen folder and adding it manually (same as above, BuildConfig is created, but no R)
- Running Android Lint and checking for errors (some performance warnings but NO errors)

The same result each time:

[image]

I got no idea what the hell is wrong there. Any suggestions?

Comment: check ur xml file some if ur not check!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I checked the manifest manually, it's OK, also there're like 40+ layouts in the project which were checked by Android Lint as I mentioned above

Comment: Can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455018/eclipse-android-errors-running-builder-android-pre-compiler-on-project  . he has similar problem as urs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use SVN as a source control? Android pre compiler now crashes because of some SVN files, solution is to upgrade SVN from 1.6 to 1.7, at least in my case that did the trick... If not look for the files with no extension (image instead of the image.png) they tend to confuse him...

See my [blog post](https://medium.com/nemanja-kovacevic/svn-android-pre-compiler-and-mac-os-x-pita-combination-beaeff119a92) for details...

Comment: thanks, that got me to thinking the right way. Resolved the problem by creating a ressource filter and exluding anything containing .svn