# Unable to start a new Android Application on Apple MacPro

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to the Android development scene. I'm using an Apple MacPro running Maverick OS. Just downloaded the ADT bundle, updated tools using SDK Manager and ran Eclipse. Started a New Android Application Project, completed the details as required with a Blank Activity. I get the following error once I click the finish button.

The error window displays the following:

> 'Building workspace' has encountered a problem. Errors occurred during
>   the build. Details -> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running
>   builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'MyFirst'.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I tried re-starting but no change. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have enough rep points to post a comment.

Try this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455018/eclipse-android-errors-running-builder-android-pre-compiler-on-project), I think it might help you solve your problem.