# Cannot launch Android app from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am unable to launch any Android app from Eclipse version:

```
Eclipse Standard/SDK
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819
```

I get the following error every time:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'GetStockQuote'.
sun/security/x509/X500Name
```

but I am able to sign, install, and run from the command line just fine.  I tried adding a Oracle SDK as suggested, specifying the JVM from eclipse.ini, etc.  Any ideas on how to figure out the issue?  Is there a log file that would give more detail?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Have you configured the Android SDK to work with Eclipse? When exactly do you get the error?

Comment: Yes, I have the android SDK installed. I am able to launch SDK Manager as well as emulator. I get this error when I try and right click on a project/activity and do a run as android application. The apk file gets created/compiled just fine. Since this does not work, I go to command line to sign the apk file and install it on emulator.

Comment: Is it possible that the issue is eclipse is unable to sign the apk file? I noticed that when it fails, I have to delete the meta directory and resign it before I install it again....seems that when I launch from run-as...it does not sign it... my vm command in ini file is as follows: -vm C:\glassfish3\jdk7\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: Are you using SVN? If so, check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14457430/483628