# Unable to clean all projects with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, git, svn, tortoisegit

So my problem is that now that I have switched from SVN to Git I cannot clean all projects with Eclipse without getting following error:

`'Cleaning all projects' has encountered a problem.`

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'com.example.myproject'.
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
Could not delete '/com.example.myproject/bin/.git'.
```

It's not clear to me why .git folder even exists under bin, inside it there is folder objects/pack and some IDX and PACK files.

I cannot remove the folder manually since it says that the IDX file is open in another program. Looks like to be TortoiseGit status cache.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14457430

Comment: Do you have any library project ?

Comment: I have google-play-services_lib imported along my project.

Answer (score 1):

Following fixed my problem:

```
1.Open properties of project in Eclipse then Resources -> Resource filters.
2.Click the "Add..." button -> Check "Exclude all", "Files and folders", "All children".
  In the text entry box input ".git" (without quotes).
3.Restart Eclipse.
```