# ADT still not allowing creation of Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adt

I downloaded `adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321` and have updated the SDK and ADT as necessary.  I am still unable to create a new Android Application Project.  When clicking finish, it still returns

```
'Building Workspace' has encountered a problem.
Errors occurred during the build
```

Clicking `details` reveals:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
    Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'MyFirstApp3'.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The project does, however, get created, except that all the packages are empty.

If, however, at the second step of the creation wizard, I uncheck `Create Activity`, the project gets successfully created and with all the proper package contents.  If I try to add a new `Android Activity` to the src folder, at the final step upon clicking `finish` nothing happens. The wizard doesn't even close; I'm left with the `back`, `cancel` and `finish` buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Create a txt file named project.properties, then if you are getting error this message

"Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one"
Then go through project menu

project->properties->android->choose & set the "project build target".
then build it.

Just setup a valid project.properties file for that project.
**Edits:**
And please post your Logcat if this doesn't solve your problem . Without Logcat it's hard to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Thanks Batman.  Where do I create this text file? Home directory?  Workspace?  bundle folder?

Comment: Actually.  The project already has a project.properoties file int he root of its directory structure.

Comment: Try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455018/eclipse-android-errors-running-builder-android-pre-compiler-on-project

Comment: Please assume I have already searched for the solution.  Also that is for  21.0.1. We are up to 22.6.3

Comment: Try downloading Android support Library from Extras.

Comment: already installed.  Nobody has a solution to this? I can't believe nobody has a solution to this

Comment: @StuartKuredjian did you solved your problem? if you did please do tell us .

Comment: no. Nobody seems to have a solution that works. I even added the 22.3 version to my Kepler version of eclipse because I'm told 22.3 works.  Same issue.