# Can't create Android Application Project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have a problem with creating Android Application project in Eclipse on my Mac. When I start Android Application Project Wizard after clicking "finish" in the last step, this window appears:

[image: Eclipse error]

I've been trying to solve this for hours, but none of the solutions I've found on the internet worked for me (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455018/eclipse-android-errors-running-builder-android-pre-compiler-on-project)). I didn't try to reinstall eclipse itself, but to I don't want to do this. What's the solution to my problem.

**UPDATE:**

I removed Eclipse and sdk from my computer and downloaded the whole ADT Bundle from [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and switched workspace but actually I am still getting the same Errors.

Comment: I actually do think redownloading and reinstalling ADT would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found up on the internet was that you could have upgraded your java. So this occurred. The solution to this problem for Mac is to edit the Eclipse.ini file to use java 1.6 .The code Below will work :

```
 -vm/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Commands/java
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a clean slate. Unistall Eclipse and redownload - Eclipse is a very big program and can be very buggy at times for no reason. While it is not the quickest solution, ensuring that Eclipse was properly downloaded and installed will provide a good foundation for the future development of you Android applications. Did you install Eclipse just for Android, or did you have a pre-existing copy and want to install the Android SDK?

Comment: I have a pre-existing copy which I used for java development. I downloaded SDK and followed all steps from google's tutorial, but as you can see it does not work.