# Eclipse ADK: Errors in Main Activity and Rec

Tags: java, android, xml, adk, eclipse-luna

I have been following the instructions for the Android Bootcamp youtube series (3. Hello World) as closely as possible, but I have run into a whole slough of issues:

## Problem 1: AVD Manager

Eclipse won't recognize my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5) for debugging/running apps. It doesn't show up in the AVD at all.

- I have downloaded the driver required for my comp to communicate with the phone
- I have enabled Developer's Mode on my phone
- I have enabled debugging over USB
- I have restarted Eclipse AND my phone
- The phone is new, undamaged and runs just fine
- My computer recognizes my phone and attributes the correct name, can extract files, etc

## Problem 2: Running Apps

I attempted to circumvent the AVD Manager by clicking "Run" to simply select my phone. However, after electing to run as an "Android Application," I got an error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'XXX'
```

I resolved this error by installing new software from (`Help > Install new Software > http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna > 'Collaboration' > 'Subversive SVN JDT Ignore Extensions' and 'Subversive SVN Team Provider'`) via the recommendation made on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455018/eclipse-android-errors-running-builder-android-pre-compiler-on-project). This made the error disappear.

Unfortunately, while the error no longer appears, the application still refuses to run. There are errors now in:

```
HelloWorld1 (ERRORS)
    src (ERRORS)
        com.example.helloworld1 (ERRORS)
            HelloWorldActivity.java (ERRORS)
```

and

```
rec (ERRORS)
    values (ERRORS)
        values-v11 (ERRORS)
            values-vw820dp (ERRORS)
```

Sadly, I don't know when the errors appeared, but I do know that they are preventing me from running anything.

I have attempted cleaning the project, but it fails every time and does not return a warning or message.

The only file I have touched since creating the project is the xml fragment. I click-and-dragged a couple elements in the Graphical Layout, then removed them. I have not touched any code, except the hex color code used to change the font color for "Hellow World" in the HelloWorldActivity. the hex color code is correct and works just fine.

Code for XML frag:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.helloworld1.HelloWorldActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for `HelloWorldActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.helloworld1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hello_world, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have been dealing with nothing but errors for 4 days. I haven't gotten to do any actual work yet. I'm at wit's end.

Any and all help is deeply, deeply appreciated.

Comment: I created a totally new project and re-tried running the project without touching anything. Finally, my phone showed up and the program displayed perfectly. However, I'm still curious as to what I did to deserve all those errors.

Comment: Eclipse can be really funky sometimes.  Was going to recommend you start over completely with a new reinstall, glad you found a faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a problem from your configuration

compare Project->Properties between your buggy project and the new one you created