# Eclipse: could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

Today I've launched Eclipse as usual but I got this error saying:

> Eclipse could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK

The error had a path to my Eclipse folder and actually there was no `tools` folder in it. Then I tried to open the Android SDK Manager and I got this error:

> [2015-10-26 09:10:41 - SDK Manager] Missing %s file in Android SDK.
>   [2015-10-26 09:10:41 - SDK Manager] android

Does anyone know how can I possibly fix this? Because really I have no idea, by googling I haven't found any answer because I haven't recently installed Eclipse, I have it installed for like 5 months now and I never had this kind of problems

**EDIT:**

I've Installed again the sdk but now when I click the libs of my projects I get this error:

> Preference node "org.eclipse.jdt.core" has been removed.

Goddamn Eclipse.... Can someone give me any kind of hint on how to fix this please

Comment: Did you recently delete or move the Android SDK? Perhaps try reinstalling the SDK and the Android Eclipse plugin.

Comment: @nneonneo nono I never moved the SDK, but the folder 'tools' is gone, I have seriously no idea on what has happened

Comment: Well, reinstall it then. I guess that would solve the problem. Not worth trying to figure out why it's missing.

Comment: @nneonneo I was hoping It would've fix the problem but now I get another one.. i've edited the question with the error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804558/android-build-errors

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Yeah I found that too but I wasn't considering about creating another workspace.. I'm going to face 1 million other issues..

Comment: @Signo, Then, I wouldn't want to be you. I remember working with Eclipse and I always had to reinstall everything, including creating new workspaces at times.